# angularjs and google maps - ng-click works in root but not in scope

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

Why is it that in order for getDirections to be called, it has to be in $root ? My ui-gmap below is already assigned to a controller via routes. Here is its source:

```
             angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) { 
              //this works
              $scope.$root.getDirections = function () {alert('here')};

              //this should work!
              $scope.getDirections = function () {alert('here')};
            }
```

HTML

```
            <ui-gmap-google-map center='mapInfo.map.center' zoom='mapInfo.map.zoom'>
             <ui-gmap-marker coords="mapInfo.marker.coords" options="mapInfo.marker.options" idkey="mapInfo.marker.id">
             <ui-gmap-window ng-cloak closeClick="closeClick()">
                <ui-gmaps-window>
                    <a ng-click="getDirections()" class="location" href="#">Doesnt work</a>
                    <a ng-click="$root.getDirections()" class="location" href="#">works</a>
                </ui-gmaps-window>      
              </ui-gmap-window>
          </ui-gmap-marker>
      </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Comment: where is your controller located in html?

Comment: Yes, make sure this `<ui-gmap-google-map>` element is within your `<div ng-contorller="MainCtrl">` controller to have access to its functions.

Comment: My controller is in my routes. @floribon  I'd rather have my controller in  my routes and not in the view....

Comment: Ok. Well I dont know about that ui-gmap directives, if they have an isolated scope indeed you cannot do that but I doubt it.